# Using #if-#else-#endif in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have 2 versions of the same program with only little changes between the two. Instead of having separate files, I use `#if defined (PAR)` - `#else` - `#endif` and then compile with or without `-cpp -DPAR` to switch between the 2 versions. I like this way as you only have to work on a single hs file. However, since my aim is to write parallel/optimised version of the original program, I wonder if using `#if-#else#-endif` has any performance implication? Basically I would like an explanation of how this works under the hood. Thanks

```
#if defined(PAR)
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq
#endif

#if defined(PAR)
test = sum ( map expensiveFunc myList `using` strat )
    where strat = parListChunk 100 rseq
#else 
test = sum ( map expensiveFunc myList )
#endif
```

**Note:**

Instead of the `-cpp` flag, you could use the language options in your source file:

e.g. `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`

But you still need to provide (or not) `-Dxxx` when compiling in order to choose which part of the program the compiler should ignore ( where xxx is the defined variable in the hs file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C preprocessor directives are in effect only during compilation. The compiler simply cuts out the lines within the #ifdef block and then compiles the program as usual, so there is no runtime performance penalty.